# JDK or Java required for SVN 1.9

Tags: java, svn, installation, system, requirements

SVN documentation says nothing about Java/JDK requirements for running the subversion. 
Ref: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/subversion.html

**do we need Java/JDK for running SVN protocol (Svnserve program). either install document or svnbook says java is required, but still i doubt if any of the svn binaries uses java or not.**

[ Closed]

Comment: Why do you doubt it?  What make you think SVN needs Java in any way?  There is any number of technologies which is not mentioned, so why is it that you think it's Java and not say Ruby which it needs?

Comment: You are right. The doubt is because of the line in configure help options.  --with-jdk=PATH  Try to use 'PATH/include' to find the JNI headers.If PATH is not specified, look for a Java Development Kit at JAVA_HOME.
I thought SVN configure will use default java available on the system under linux. Thanks for clear answer Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do we need Java/JDK for running SVN protocol (Svnserve program)?

No.

The instructions that you link to refer to an optional requirement for JDK 1.8, but that is only for building the Java bindings; i.e. the library that allows you to access SVN from a Java application.  The SVN binaries don't depend on the Java bindings.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for explanation. I was having doubt in --JAVA_HOME options and was not clear about java bindings.